# jsdom + canvas on node.js: toDataURL() error

Tags: node.js, canvas, jsdom

Using canvas@1.2.3 & jsdom@3.1.2 with node v0.12.2, I'm getting an error while trying to use the canvas `toDataURL()` function.

canvasTest.js:

```
$(function(){
  var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').attr({'id':'canvasTest', 'width':'500', 'height':'500'});

  var ctx=canvas[0].getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();

  $('#canvasWrap').append(canvas);
});
```

HTML Test:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="canvasTest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  console.log($('body').html());
  console.log($('#canvasTest').length);
  console.log($('#canvasTest')[0].toDataURL());
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvasWrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

jsdom Test:

```
var canvas = require('canvas');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env({
  html: '<html><body><div id="canvasWrap"></div></body></html>',
  scripts: ['127.0.0.1/jquery-2.1.4.min.js','127.0.0.1/canvasTest.js'],
  done:function (err,win) {
    var $ = win.jQuery;
    $(function(){
      console.log($('body').html());
      console.log($('#canvasTest').length);
      console.log($('#canvasTest')[0].toDataURL());
    });
  }
});
```

On my HTML Test in Chrome I get the correct base64-encoded canvas data, while in node.js, the error reads:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the purpose of jsdom here? Does canvas.toDataURL() work? Did you create something in canvas? Why are you using: $('canvas')[0].toDataURL() ?

Comment: What version of jsdom and node?

Comment: Can you post the full example code? And yes, it's important to know what version of JSDom, Canvas and Node you're running.

Comment: Full code posted with version numbers.

Comment: Do the other console logs (body html and selector length) give you the right result?

Comment: On the HTML-side in Chrome, the selector length is `1`.  On the jsdom-side in node.js, the selector length is `0`.  Oddly, the body html reports `<div id="canvasWrap"><canvas id="canvasTest" width="500" height="500"></canvas></div>` in Chrome and `<div id="canvasWrap"><canvas style="" id="canvasTest" width="500" height="500"></canvas></div>` in node.js, so it doesn't make sense for the selector length to be `0`.

Comment: What does console.log($('#canvasTest')); output ?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting by ID, so there is no array.  Drop the [0] and it should work, or select it another way, with an array:

```
console.log($('canvas')[0].toDataURL());
```

or try this:

```
console.log($('#canvasTest').toDataURL());
```

or this:

```
console.log(win.$("#canvasTest").toDataURL());
```

or this:

```
console.log(win.document.getElementById("canvasTest").toDataURL());
```

or this:

```
console.log(win.document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL());
```

Comment: I tried this just now, I'm getting the same error as OP, with `$('#canvasTest').toDataURL()`